# Why would a magnetic sight glass indicate a wrong water level in a surge tank?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, measurements

In a pumping station that i work, there is a magnetic sight glass attached to a surge tank which I guess there is something wrong about it because when I isolate the tube, drain it and reopen the air and water valve, the level doesn't rise!
So can anybody tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: blockage either side of the valves?

Comment: either the tank is empty, the valve isn't really open, or there is a blockage.  You test a sight glass by opening the drain.  The level should drop then bounce back up when you close the drain.  This is known as bouncing the glass.

Comment: I don't think there is a blockage because when i close the upper valve and open the lower one the level rockets to the upmost part and then when i open the lower valve it doesn't drop down!

Comment: the tank isn't empty because i can see water coming out of the lower valve and when i open the drain while the valves are open, water comes out without bouncing level!

Comment: Maybe the tube is gunked up and the magnet is sticking? Can you take it apart?

Comment: Actually I took the magnet apart and there was nothing wrong about it